# Actions On Google with TypeScript: How to start?

Tags: typescript, actions-on-google

I'm using the Actions Console.
When invoking my action with "HookIntent" I always get:

```
{
    "error": "No intent was provided and fallback handler is not defined."
}
```

My index.ts:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import {
    dialogflow
} from 'actions-on-google'

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('HookIntent', (conv) => {
    const response = "Hello Test"
    conv.add(response)
})

exports.playMusicFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Json:

```
{
    "handler": {
        "name": "HookIntent"
    },
    "intent": {
        "name": "HookIntent",
...
```

I cannot find any working example with typescript. All examples and trainings from google are with Javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is directly related to typescript, the code you show doesn't use much Typescript features. The error shows that something could be up with the Dialogflow setup. Do you have a default fallback setup in your Dialogflow agent?

Comment: Currently I am only using the Action Console, as I thought I read something that this is the future technology and Dialogflow is old? I even think I got the message to convert my previously created dialogflow agent to Actions, so I did that... So I do not have any Dialogflow agent configured, currently. I even can reproduce that error locally with "firebase serve" and then send the post to that local url.

Comment: Ah, yes it is true that Google recently released an update to their Actions platform. In your code you are using `import { dialogflow } from "actions-on-google"` This is the handler for integrating actions on google with Dialogflow. Since you are not using Dialogflow this could explain the error as those two platforms handle intents differently. I have no experience with the new update, but I think you have to look for the correct handler for the new version of actions to make this work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to agree with Jordi in the comments you should instead use [`@assistant/conversation`](https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-nodejs/) and refactor a bit of your code to use the Actions Builder platform webhook.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import {
    conversation
} from '@assistant/conversation'

const app = conversation({debug: true})

app.handle('HookIntent', (conv) => {
    const response = "Hello Test"
    conv.add(response)
})

exports.playMusicFunction = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Comment: This works great and is now in my opinion a very good "hello world" example how to use google actions in the latest version with firebase functions and TypeScript.

Comment: I found some (current) documentation here: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/overview